# Difference operator endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Let $\delta : R_{p}[x] \to R_{p}[X] $ the endomorphism of $R_{p}[X]$ such that : $\delta(P(X)) = P(X + 1) - P(X)$ , what is the kernel of $\delta$ ?  (i tried to compute it explicitly but that was a dead end ) .

EDIT : $R_{p}[X]$  is the set of real polynomials of degree less than or equal to $p$ .

Comment: Are we supposed to know what $R_p$ is?

Comment: Can you compute the degree of $\delta(P)$ with respect to the degree of $P$ ?

Comment: Which ring is this for?

Comment: @Bebop ok , got it . it is $deg(p) - 1$ so in order to be in the kernel it have to be a constant , right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\delta\bigl(P(X)\bigr)=0$ then you have $P(n+1)=P(n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, hence the polynomial $P(X)-P(0)$ has infinitely many roots, so it must be the zero polynomial. Consequently $P(X)=P(0)$ is constant. The converse is obvious.